# Creating 2D data from a flat/1D list of spreadsheet entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

This seems like it'd be a really common operation, but I don't know the terminology or what to search for. I have a table like the following in CSV:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Test | Var1 | Var2 | Time |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    |    1 | 0.1  |
|    2 | A    |    2 | 0.4  |
|    3 | A    |    3 | 0.2  |
|    4 | B    |    1 | 0.3  |
|    5 | B    |    2 | 0.2  |
|    6 | B    |    3 | 0.3  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

I'd like to pull out a 2D table of `Time` values (as below), with columns `Var1=A`, `Var1=B` and rows with values in `Var2`, ultimately to produce a scatter plot.

```
+---+-----+-----+
|   |  A  |  B  |
+---+-----+-----+
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
+---+-----+-----+
```

Of course my real data is much larger and it's a rather tedious operation to do by hand. Before I run off to create a script to do it I thought libreoffice/excel might be able to do it for me. Can this be done easily and does it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking random menus is faster than searching.

Libreoffice Calc: Select, `Data->Pivot Table->Create`, Drag/Drop

[image]

If you change the source data, you'll need to `Data->Pivot Table->Refresh` (doesn't always work, sometimes a restart is necessary).

---

For excel 2007 (afaik, there's no help->about), it's `Insert->Tables->Pivot Table`, but you can't [create scatter plots](https://superuser.com/questions/812337/cant-create-a-scatter-chart-from-a-pivot-table-in-excel).